# SmartCapture form doesn't redirect to target page in iframe tag

Tags: marketing-cloud, redirect

I have a SmartCapture form created in a cloudpage. Whenever a person fills the form and submit, it will capture information and redirect to a thankyou page (also a cloudpage).

It works well until I embed the form into an external site by `<iframe>` tag. The information still can be captured but the form doesn't redirect to the target page. Seems like it was blocked

Here is the error I got from the browser console.

```
smartcapture-formjs.js:516 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at success (https://mc.s10.exacttarget.com/CloudPages/lib/smartcapture-formjs.js:516:27)
    at Object.success (https://mc.s10.exacttarget.com/CloudPages/lib/smartcapture-formjs.js:29:16)
    at j (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:2:27309)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:2:28122)
    at x (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:5:22111)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js:5:26030)
```

Disable Same Origin Policy in the external site is not a choice since the page can't be disabled alone.

I was told that I should try to fix the smartcapture page with the function `window.parent.postMessage()`. To be honest, I have no idea how this can work in this case and where I can put the function..

Anyone who has encountered this issue, please let me know how to handle this. Really appreciate with any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CORS security issue, this way will help:
Note: I don't have a chance to work with other cases so not sure if this solution can apply to a similar issue. I believe this also depends on the external site.

Go to cloudpage -> click on smart capture and edit HTML. Put the script at the bottom `<script>` block

```
const form = document.getElementById('Your smart capture form Id');
form.addEventListener('submit', () => {

// Redirect to the target page after submission
 window.top.location.href = "https://example.com/thankyou"; 

 
// Redirect within the frame
// window.location.href = "https://example.com/thankyou"; 
 });
```